# Flutter: How to JSON encode a `List` properly?

Tags: android, ios, json, http, flutter

I am trying to pass a `List` to my server using flutter, via a REST API.

Below is the code

```
 Future<void> saveOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItems) async {
    int responsetag = 0;
    try {
      await http.post("http://url to post the data",
          body: convert.json.encode(orderItems.toJson()), //This line do not work
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json"
          }).then((http.Response response) {
        final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

        print("RESPONSE: " + response.body);
        print("STATUS CODE: " + statusCode.toString());

        if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || response.body == null) {
          throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
        } else {
          responsetag = int.parse(response.body);
        }
      });

      return responsetag;
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

The above code doesn't run because I can't encode a `List` using `convert.json.encode(orderItems.toJson())`.

Below is my code for `OrderItem` bean and its serialisation class.

```
part 'order_item.g.dart';

/// An annotation for the code generator to know that this class needs the
/// JSON serialization logic to be generated.
@JsonSerializable()
class OrderItem {
  int idorderItem;
  FreshProducts freshProducts;
  Order order;
  ProductSize productSize;
  double orderItemExpectedPricePerKg;
  double orderItemQuantity;
  int dateCreated;
  int lastUpdated;

  OrderItem(
      {
        this.idorderItem,
        this.freshProducts,
        this.order,
        this.productSize,
        this.orderItemExpectedPricePerKg,
        this.orderItemQuantity,
        this.dateCreated,
        this.lastUpdated

      });

  /// A necessary factory constructor for creating a new User instance
  /// from a map. Pass the map to the generated `_$OrderItemFromJson()` constructor.
  /// The constructor is named after the source class, in this case User.
  factory OrderItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OrderItemFromJson(json);

  /// `toJson` is the convention for a class to declare support for serialization
  /// to JSON. The implementation simply calls the private, generated
  /// helper method `_$OrderItemToJson`.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$OrderItemToJson(this);
}
```

And

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'order_item.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

OrderItem _$OrderItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return OrderItem(
    idorderItem: json['idorderItem'] as int,
    freshProducts: json['freshProducts'] == null
        ? null
        : FreshProducts.fromJson(json['freshProducts'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    order: json['order'] == null
        ? null
        : Order.fromJson(json['order'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
        productSize: json['productSize'] == null
        ? null
        : ProductSize.fromJson(json['productSize'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    orderItemExpectedPricePerKg:
        (json['orderItemExpectedPricePerKg'] as num)?.toDouble(),
    orderItemQuantity: (json['orderItemQuantity'] as num)?.toDouble(),
    dateCreated: json['dateCreated'] as int,
    lastUpdated: json['lastUpdated'] as int,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$OrderItemToJson(OrderItem instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'idorderItem': instance.idorderItem,
      'freshProducts': instance.freshProducts,
      'order': instance.order,
      'productSize': instance.productSize,
      'orderItemExpectedPricePerKg': instance.orderItemExpectedPricePerKg,
      'orderItemQuantity': instance.orderItemQuantity,
      'dateCreated': instance.dateCreated,
      'lastUpdated': instance.lastUpdated,
    };
```

how can I make sure I Can pass a list to `POST` from flutter http?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar type of problem. But my `List` was wrap with a other keys like `{"data":listOfItemJson}` . So I first created a `Map` like that `var map = {"data": MainOrderController.orderModel.toJson()};`  and when i post this the uril i updated post mechanism like :

```
 var response =
          await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(map));
```

Note: `jsonEncode()` is part of `import 'dart:convert';` package.

I hope you can get an Idea

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you are using `convert.json.encode(orderItems.toJson())` but i am trying to tel you that I used to pass list of item first converting into map.  And this map is also a string format of json. I converted the list into map because my post paramer needs to wrap the json. Then i used jsonEncode() method to endcode the map. **So you can try to encode your list by using jsonEndcode()**

Comment: Using my code, can you provide me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

My take on this would be to replace `json_serializable` library with https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper

It's quite similar, but don't over-bloats your code with boilerplate and not forcing you to maintain loads of '*.g.part' files, etc.

It will help you not only for this case, but for all Dart Object => JSON => Dart Object cases.

Please carefully read library readme document first, especially section "Basic setup".

With `dart-json-mapper` your code *could* look like this:

```dart
import 'main.reflectable.dart' show initializeReflectable;
import 'package:dart_json_mapper/dart_json_mapper.dart' show jsonSerializable, JsonMapper;

@jsonSerializable
@Json(enumValues: ProductSize.values)
enum ProductSize {Big, Small}

@jsonSerializable
class Order {
// ...
}

@jsonSerializable
class FreshProducts {
// ...
}

@jsonSerializable
class OrderItem {
  int idorderItem;
  FreshProducts freshProducts;
  Order order;
  ProductSize productSize;
  double orderItemExpectedPricePerKg;
  double orderItemQuantity;
  int dateCreated;
  int lastUpdated;

  OrderItem(
      {
        this.idorderItem,
        this.freshProducts,
        this.order,
        this.productSize,
        this.orderItemExpectedPricePerKg,
        this.orderItemQuantity,
        this.dateCreated,
        this.lastUpdated

      });
}

void main {
  initializeReflectable();

  final orderItems = <OrderItem>[OrderItem(), OrderItem(), OrderItem()];

  // Instead of convert.json.encode(orderItems.toJson())
  final orderItemsJson = JsonMapper.serialize(orderItems);

  // orderItemsJson will have Json string which you could pass as body to your post request

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/651 ，you can put the following to build.yaml in root folder. The explicit_to_json default is false, set it true and it will explicitly call the nested toJson.

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          # Options configure how source code is generated for every
          # `@JsonSerializable`-annotated class in the package.
          #
          # The default value for each is listed.
          explicit_to_json: true
```